# How to extract a part of a value inside an attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have many hyperlinks with a onclick function which have differents values on this way:

```
<a onclick="Utils.decideOffer('', {'unlockFeature': 'cars'});">cars text</a>
<a onclick="Utils.decideOffer('', {'unlockFeature': 'bikes'});">bikes whatever</a>
<a onclick="Utils.decideOffer('', {'unlockFeature': 'motorcycles'});">another motor</a>
```

Now when this element is clicked I need to get the values of that array, example: "cars", or "bikes" or "motorcycles".

Don't suggest to get them from the *Utils.decideOffer* function because I need to get them without edit that file/function. This is how I intend to extract it.

```
$('a').click(function() {
    onclickValue = $(this).attr('onclick');
    if (onclickValue.length) {
      var optionSelectedValue = ??? ;
    }
});
```

I was thinking on use Regex so can you please help me on the Regex to use on this case?, or if you have another good idea to achieve this it is also welcome!

Comment: just a question, the inner text of the hyperlinks isnt supposed to be cars/bikes/motorcycles as well instead of all just "car" ? because if it is, then you can simply get the information from the inner text...

Comment: @Banana - that's too easy

Comment: @Banana the inner text of the hyperlinks are different ones, you saw "cars" in my example because I left them like that when I did the copy, I just corrected it. Thanks for the observation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `split()` like :

```
$('a').click(function() {
    onclickValue = $(this).attr('onclick');
    if (onclickValue.length) {
      var optionSelectedValue = onclickValue.split(":")[1].split("}")[0];
    }
});
```

it will return the `'cars'` or `'bikes'` or `'motorcycles'` including the quotes

See **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7h2xg9mq/)**

... or to get the value without quotes as suggested :

```
optionSelectedValue = onclickValue.split(":")[1].split("}")[0].split("'")[1];
```

See updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7h2xg9mq/1/)**

Comment: @Banana yep but it will require more split processes ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    onclickValue = $(this).attr('onclick');
    if (onclickValue.length) {
        var re = /(?!: ')+(\w)+(?='})/;
var found = onclickValue.match(re);
      var optionSelectedValue = found[0] ;
        alert(optionSelectedValue);
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/wpjh1ma7/